# How to query MS Certificate Authority Server with c#

Tags: c#, certificate, smartcard, x509certificate2, ca

I am trying to query a ca with c#

I need to do 2 things:

1. get the list of Issued Certificates and iterate over it
2. get the crl , or list of revoked certificates and iterate over it.

I couldn't find any api to do this,

I tried querying certificated through Active Directory, but I'm missing some properties there.

And I also tried querying via the Microsoft.Clm.Provision Api, but no luck there either.

Any ideas ?

**Exmaple For Querying via Active Directory**

```
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxxx", "xxxx\\administrator", "yyyyyy"); 
    DirectorySearcher dsearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);

    SearchResultCollection rc = dsearch.FindAll();

    X509Certificate[] stt = new X509Certificate[rc.Count];
    List<X509Certificate2> certificatesList = new List<X509Certificate2> { };


    foreach (SearchResult r in rc)
    {

      if (r.Properties.Contains("userCertificate"))
      {
        Byte[] b = (Byte[])r.Properties["userCertificate"][0];  
        cert1 = new X509Certificate2(b);
      }
    }
```

Comment: You have to use ICertView COM interface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385414(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I saw ICertView too, but all examples are for C++ , so I assumed this is not available for c#, couldn't find it anywhere for c#

Comment: it is available for c# as well. Just create a `CertAdmin` interop library (to translate COM definitions to CLR) and reference the library in your project.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I'm sorry , this is Chinese to me :)